# Form value field is visable in localhost but not on live site-how to hide?

Tags: jquery, forms, localhost

I'm almost completed moving my first live site to my new xampp setup on localhost.

I have a form that uses jquery in the header of the site.

It's a bit verbose, but here it is:

```
<div class="outeremailcontainer">
    <div id="emailcontainer">
  <?php include('verify.php'); ?>
      <form action="index_success.php" method="post" id="sendEmail" class="email">
        <h3 class="register2">Newsletter Signup:</h3>
        <ul class="forms email">
         <li class="name"><label for="yourName">Name: </label>
     <input type="text" name="yourName" class="info" id="yourName" value="<?= $_POST['yourName']; ?>" /><br />
    </li>

    <li class="city"><label for="yourCity">City: </label>
     <input type="text" name="yourCity" class="info" id="yourCity" value="<?= $_POST['yourCity']; ?>" /><br />
    </li>

          <li class="email"><label for="emailFrom">Email: </label>
             <input type="text" name="emailFrom" class="info" id="emailFrom" value="<?= $_POST['emailFrom']; ?>" />
             <?php if(isset($emailFromError)) echo '<span class="error">'.$emailFromError.'</span>';
             ?>
          </li>

           <li class="buttons email">
             <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
             <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
           </li>

        </ul>
      </form>
    <div class="clearing">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I am using jQuery (I can include the function if need-be) and it hides fields, etc.

The problem is that on the localhost site, the values of the fields are populating the fields.

IE: first field has this in the box, etc

```
<?= $_POST['yourName']; ?>
```

It works great in the live site though.

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: This feels like a ServerFault question. Are you saying the site broke when you moved it to your new server?

Comment: Really?  jQuery, works on live site, php forms showing values in one place and not another?  Obvious coding issue is what must be resolved...I disagree.  I'm saying that the form fields are showing the "value" of each field in localhost for some reason...

Comment: I may just be misunderstanding. I thought you meant that the PHP was working properly until you changed servers. My apologies if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are seeing the PHP code in the input box rather than the result of the form field value previously posted.

Check your php.ini file.  I'm not much of a PHP programmer, but I believe there is a setting in there to allow the `<?=` shortcut.  I *think* it's

> short_open_tag = 1

That may be the reason you see the PHP code in the input box.

Alternatively, you could turn on `asp_tags` and use the `<%= %>` notation.

Comment: Hey-awesome-that was it.  I actually just changed the fields to <?php echo ...  and they work now.  Thanks again!